# How can we change Xcode server notification email download link to https?

Tags: ios, xcode

We've recently gotten the xcode server to generate builds for us. However the "Download Product" button has a link like http://ibuildbox.mydomain.com/xcs/install/f3011093-ee03-4db1-b527-a02b84129cd7

When that link is followed on a device it gives an error indicating the the cert is invalid.

If we copy the link manually and make it be https then the app will install.

[image]

How can we change the email to have this link be an https link so that the app will install on a device by clicking on the email?